# make angular ng-if reserve space for showing if event occurs

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs

I have a set up in which I am having a modal form for some details to be submitted. But when one of the text-field is put blank - generating a label below the text-field saying "it is required" causes "Proceed" button to move - (Infact all others below it to move). How can make DOM to reserve space for such labels - while I am using ng-if of angularjs.

My question visually is shown in below image[image]

code is as follows:

```html
<div class="col-md-5">
    <input type="text" name="userFirstName" ng-model="registerAppCtrl.registerAppDetails.user.fn" id="reg-fname" class="form-control" tabindex="1" placeholder="First Name" autofocus required/> 
    <div class="error-help">
        <p ng-if="customerDetailsForm.userFirstName.$invalid && !customerDetailsForm.userFirstName.$pristine">First name is required</p>
    </div>
        
    <input type="email" name="userEmailId" ng-model="registerAppCtrl.registerAppDetails.user.email" id="reg-email" class="form-control" tabindex="3"  placeholder="E-mail ID" required/>
    <div class="error-help">
        <p ng-if="customerDetailsForm.userEmailId.$error.required && !customerDetailsForm.userEmailId.$pristine">Email ID is required</p>
        <p ng-if="customerDetailsForm.userEmailId.$dirty && customerDetailsForm.userEmailId.$error.email" ng-hide="customerDetailsForm.userEmailId.$pristine">Email ID is invalid</p>
    </div>
    <input type="text" name="userName" ng-model="registerAppCtrl.registerAppDetails.user.uname" id="reg-uname" class="form-control" tabindex="5"  placeholder="User Name" onkeyup="unameAvailability($(this).val())" required/>
    <span id="uname-check" style="opacity: 0;"><i class="fa"></i><i id="avail-message"></i></span>
</div>
        
<div class="col-md-5 col-md-offset-1">
    <input type="text" name="userLastName" ng-model="registerAppCtrl.registerAppDetails.user.ln" id="reg-lname" class="form-control"  tabindex="2" placeholder="Last Name" required/>
    <div class="error-help">
        <p ng-if="customerDetailsForm.userLastName.$invalid && !customerDetailsForm.userLastName.$pristine">Last name is required</p>
    </div> 
<input type="number" name="userPhoneNo" ng-model="registerAppCtrl.registerAppDetails.user.phone" id="reg-phone" class="form-control" tabindex="4" placeholder="Phone" required/>
<div class="error-help">
    <p ng-if="customerDetailsForm.userPhoneNo.$invalid && !customerDetailsForm.userPhoneNo.$pristine">Phone number is required</p>
</div> 
        
<input type="password" name="userPassword" ng-model="registerAppCtrl.registerAppDetails.user.pass" id="reg-pwd" class="form-control" tabindex="6" placeholder="Password" required/>
    <div class="error-help">
        <p ng-if="customerDetailsForm.userPassword.$invalid && !customerDetailsForm.userPassword.$pristine">Password is required</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-12">
    <button class="btn btn-proceed1"  tabindex="7"  ng-disabled="customerDetailsForm.$invalid" ng-click="registerAppCtrl.fadeProceed('tab1', 'tab2');" style="position: fixed;" >Proceed</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can reserve space by using another `<p>` element in your case using `ng-hide` and `visibility:hidden;`  :

```
<div class="error-help">
    <p ng-if="customerDetailsForm.userPhoneNo.$invalid &&!customerDetailsForm.userPhoneNo.$pristine">Phone number is required</p>

    <p style="visibility:hidden;" ng-hide="customerDetailsForm.userPhoneNo.$invalid &&!customerDetailsForm.userPhoneNo.$pristine" >Phone number is required</p>

</div>
```

Comment: I don't think your solution will work, bacause the `ng-hide` will apply `display: none`, thus overriding your `visibility: hidden`.

Comment: That is the purpose. When `ng-hide` is used its `display` will be `none`. So that the the `<p>` element using `ng-if` will show. If not, the button will still be pushed downwards, when the `<p>` element with ng-if appears. @VladimirZdenek

Comment: Ok, I see it now. But that means you have to define your conditions and error messages twice.

Comment: nope I tryed that, It does not reserve space plus when it is supposed to show some error like "First name is required" - it just adds space i.e your solution would hide element when it is to be showned.

In simple words - it does not work.

Comment: I cant think of any reason why it shouldnt work. Maybe for the second `<p>` element that has `visibility:hidden` use and `ng-if` with opposing value instead of `ng-show`. **Eg.** `ng-if="!customerDetailsForm.userLastName.$invalid || customerDetailsForm.userLastName.$pristine"` **Note:** Instead of using and `&&`, use or `||`. @michaelcorleone

Comment: @ErnestSoo - sorry, I made a mistake understanding your answer you were and are correct.  Thanks a ton. :)

Comment: A combination of `$invalid || $untouched` would also be better in `ng-hide`

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is more of a workaround. You can replace `ng-if` with `ng-class`. You can give your errors a class based on your conditions - for example `invisible`. In the CSS you will define the invisible class as:

```
.invisible {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

managed to do it using `[ngStyle]`

```
[ngStyle]="{'visibility': my-flag ? 'visible' : 'hidden'}"
```